# Including CSS File in TYPO3 Backend?

Tags: php, css, backend, typo3

I am trying to include my cascading style sheet into my TYPO3 extension. I created the extension with "kickstarter". This is the way I tried to include it:

```
$this->doc->getPageRenderer()->addCssFile(t3lib_extMgm::extRelPath('myExt') . 'res/css/my_stylesheet.css');
```

I added that line at the end of the `main()` method.
So what am I doing wrong? The path including the file does definately exist.

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, I could finally solve the problem.

When adding the code right after instancing the "doc" object, everything works fine.

```
$this->doc = t3lib_div::makeInstance('mediumDoc');
$this->doc->getPageRenderer()->addCssFile(t3lib_extMgm::extRelPath('myExt') . 'res/css/my_stylesheet.css');
```

Answer (score 7):

And if You would like to include CSS file in other module than Yours, without to modify it, You could use $TBE_STYLES array.

ext_tables.php:

```
// Custom CSS include
if (TYPO3_MODE=="BE")   {
    $TBE_STYLES['inDocStyles_TBEstyle'] .= '@import "/typo3conf/ext/your_ext/res/css/your.css";';
}
```

Comment: I like this option better, it also works in extensions which don't have an own BE module.

Comment: Should use  `\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::extRelPath()` to have a solution that does not rely on the instance being on the "root" of the domain.

Answer (score 1):

Belo given trick will work for TYPO3 8.7.X version

> Step-1 Add following lines in ext_tables.php file

```
$GLOBALS['TBE_STYLES']['skins'][$_EXTKEY]['name'] = $_EXTKEY;
$GLOBALS['TBE_STYLES']['skins'][$_EXTKEY]['stylesheetDirectories']['css'] = 'EXT:'.$_EXTKEY.'/stylesheets/visual/';
```

> Step-2: Define css file with any name at the given path (in our case
>   its '**stylesheets/visual/**' inside the extension)