# How to hide buttons (edit,rename,delete...) from typo3 DAM File module for User?

Tags: typo3, dam

I want to hide  DAM(file module) ICON (info,move,replace) for User  . How can i achieve this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In other words: You need to set the permissions to read-only, and hence hide the "info" icon.

**You can modify permissions** by removing the following items from access lists in the usergroup (or user) settings:

**Tables (modify):**

- Media
- Media Category
- Media Types

Make sure they are still selected in the **Tables (listing)** part.
[DAM extension manual > user permissions](http://typo3.org/extension-manuals/dam/1.1.1/view/1/4/#c1608)

**To disable the "info" button** (which is not so straightforward) you might consider using a custom backend css and hide it by setting a "display:none;" property. Use this hint to include a single css file via extTables.php: [Including CSS File in TYPO3 Backend?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5192342/including-css-file-in-typo3-backend)

Read more:
[$TBE_STYLES and custom css in TYPO3 backend](http://blog.bigbabou.org/2009/tbe_styles-and-custom-css-in-typo3-backend/)